# What does AdornedElementPlaceholder exactly do when we use it in validation controlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

After going through several articles and examples showing usage of

> AdornedElementPlaceholder

i am still confused that what is the exact functionality it incorporates to xaml validation?

Answer (score 22):

If you use Validations you need to show the user where (and what) failed to validated and that’s where `AdornedElementPlaceholder` comes into play. It is a Placeholder that has exactly the same size of the UIElement you’re validating.

Let’s say you’re validating user input on a `TextBox` and want to show a red box around the `TextBox` when the validation fails. Define a ValidationRule and a validation template for the `TextBox`. If the ValidationRule fails, then the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` is shown on your `TextBox`. Inside the template the `AdornedElementPlaceholder` tells the Framework where to place your template on the UI. In our case the template might look like this:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You should read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation).

Comment: You are trying to say that it will take the same size as UIElement? One more question what do you mean by this line " Inside the template the AdornedElementPlaceholder tells the Framework where to place your template." ??

Comment: See the liked article for examples.

Comment: The Template on its own doesn’t know where it should draw itself. The Placeholder links the Template to the UIElement. Best way to see how it works is to try it out. Put something inside the Placeholder and put something around the Placeholder.

Comment: well explain, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe the AdornedElementPlaceholder is used to show where the "validation indicator element" is positioned in relation to the control being validated.
I.e. if you have a text box and when validation fails a red x appears on the right of the box, I believe (although not 100%) that the AdornedElementPlaceholder is responsible for that positioning.

> Represents the element used in a ControlTemplate to specify where a
>   decorated control is placed relative to other elements in the
>   ControlTemplate.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.adornedelementplaceholder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i have already visited this link but still the concept not clear that how does it do that?